# Unable to use Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sqlite, mono, visual-studio-2019, monodevelop

Good afternoon,

I wrote some code with MonoDevelop on Linux. The program that i'm writing use Sqlite to store datas, so i've imported the `Mono.Data.Sqlite`, and it work perfectly.

[MonoDeveloper imported libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrT53.png)

When i tried to copy the project on Windows and opened with Visual Studio 2019, i've got some troubles.

First of all, VS tells me that the library was not found.

[VS2019 imported libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf4Ej.png)

When i try to compile VS throws me the error [CS0246](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0246), that says that the type or namespace name "Mono" could not be found.

I've tried to reimported the Dll. The library was imported successfully, so that the code compiles without problems, but when I try to run the program, another error is thrown:

> `System.BadImageFormatException`
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Data.Sqlite, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies. (HRESULT:0x80131058).

I'm compiling with x86.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You shouldn't be 'copying' anything except the source files.  Any bin/obj files will be in the wrong format.   Close the solution, delete bin/obj folders, and reopen the solution, then the correct dlls should be restored.

Comment: @Neil i've tried, but sadly unsuccessfully. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Davide Parisi: Try the following. **1)** Remove reference to the `Mono.Data.sqlite`. **2)** In the Visual Studio go to _Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution_... Select Browse, find `Mono.data.sqlite` package and install it. **3)** Try recompile the solution.

Comment: @Jackdaw damn, I thought I had tried this solution, but apparently not. Thanks a lot!

If you enter this comment as the answer I mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases, especially when moving project on a another computer, the following steps can help to prepare environment to compile projects, that require the NuGet `Mono.data.sqlite` package:

1. Remove reference to the `Mono.Data.sqlite` from the project's
   references.
2. In the Visual Studio go to `Tools` ► `NuGet Package Manager` ►
   `Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...` Then select `Browse`, find
   `Mono.data.sqlite` package and install it.
3. Recompile the solution.